# PHP Twitter post using oAuth and 403 error

Tags: php, string, twitter

Im having an issue with posting to Twitter, using oAuth, and recieving a 403 error. Let me explain:

Having done all the authentication and 'running' this:

```
$message = "Some text";
$oauth->post('statuses/update', array("status" => $message));
```

The message appears on Twitter, I get a 200 response and all is well.

However when I try and use:

```
$message = $text;
$oauth->post('statuses/update', array("status" => $message));
```

Now `$text` is fetched from some `XML`, using `SimpleXMLElement` in PHP. I then use `$text = $entry->summary;` to store the string I want to tweet. Im already checking that the text is < 140 characters so I know the text is of the correct length.

However when running the code I get a `403` error.

Here is an example of the contents of `$message`, which contains `$text` from `var_dump`:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(4) "html" } [0]=> string(104) "Attempting a PHP script to tweet something when it features the hashtag #tweeted and is under 140 chars." }
```

I thought it might be the `#` being in there that was causing the problem but I can confirm that I can tweet using the first example containing a hash with no problems.

Do I need to encode or decode the string in some way before sending it on to Twitter? Im confused.

Comment: If you inspect the outgoing request data does it look as you expect it to?

Comment: Any ideas on how I might be able to do that? How can I check the post?

Comment: Thinking potentially I need something like: $message = urlencode(utf8_encode($text));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to send an **object** $text as a string.

So anything that converts SimpleXmlElement object to string should work. I think even plain simple `$message = (string)$text` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = urldecode($text);
```

Problem solved.